# Transform pyspark dataframe row value as a relation of other elements in the same row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to transform spark dataframe row value as a relation of every other value of the same row. I plan to do this by maintaining a list of all rows elements and mapping it to individual row values. Better illustrated by the below example

**Input dataframe**

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('1111','1010', 'aaaa'), ('2222','2020', 'bbbb'), ('3333','3030', 'cccc')], ['company_id', 'client_id', 'partner_id'])
>>> df.show()
+----------+---------+----------+
|company_id|client_id|partner_id|
+----------+---------+----------+
|      1111|     1010|      aaaa|
|      2222|     2020|      bbbb|
|      3333|     3030|      cccc|
+----------+---------+----------+
```

**Expected output**

```
+------+------------------+
|entity|         relations|
+------+------------------+
|  1111|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  2222|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  3333|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
|  1010|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  2020|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  3030|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
|  aaaa|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  bbbb|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  cccc|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
+------+------------------+
```

I have implemented the below code and could achieve the expected output. But the data in this actual dataframe is expected to be very huge, so just wanna check if there is a better approach to solve this.

**My Implementation**

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def unionAll(*dfs):
   return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

df = spark.createDataFrame([('1111','1010', 'aaaa'), ('2222','2020', 'bbbb'), ('3333','3030', 'cccc')], ['company_id', 'client_id', 'partner_id'])
company_df = df.select(df.company_id.alias('entity'), F.array(df.company_id, df.client_id, df.partner_id).alias('relations'))
client_df = df.select(df.client_id.alias('entity'), F.array(df.company_id, df.client_id, df.partner_id).alias('relations'))
partner_df = df.select(df.partner_id.alias('entity'), F.array(df.company_id, df.client_id, df.partner_id).alias('relations'))
entity_df = unionAll(company_df, client_df, partner_df)
entity_df.show()
+------+------------------+
|entity|         relations|
+------+------------------+
|  1111|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  2222|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  3333|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
|  1010|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  2020|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  3030|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
|  aaaa|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  bbbb|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  cccc|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
+------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out. You just have to make another column with those lists, that's it. Then you can even drop whatever you want to drop. It is computationally less expensive than your code :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1111','1010', 'aaaa'), ('2222','2020', 'bbbb'), ('3333','3030', 'cccc')], ['company_id', 'client_id', 'partner_id'])

df = df.withColumn('relation', [df['company_id'], df['client_id'], df['partner_id']])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually improved my code, by adding a new column and then using explode function to get the expected output. Pls refer above.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved upon my previous implementation as below, incase someone finds it helpful.

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

to_list = F.udf(lambda *x: filter(None, x), T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1111','1010', 'aaaa'), ('2222','2020', 'bbbb'), ('3333','3030', 'cccc')], ['company_id', 'client_id', 'partner_id'])
df = df.withColumn('relations', to_list(df['company_id'], df['client_id'], df['partner_id']))
transformed_df = df.select(F.explode(to_list(df.company_id, df.client_id, df.partner_id)).alias('entity'), df.relations)

transformed_df.show()

+------+------------------+
|entity|          relation|
+------+------------------+
|  1111|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  1010|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  aaaa|[1111, 1010, aaaa]|
|  2222|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  2020|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  bbbb|[2222, 2020, bbbb]|
|  3333|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
|  3030|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
|  cccc|[3333, 3030, cccc]|
+------+------------------+
```